# Error when trying to create a print function

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have been following the [How to Print Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtext.html#interactively) tutorial on the Oracle Java Documentation website. However when I have tried to implement some of the code into my code I get an error.

```
javac PrintableForms.java
PrintableForms.java:165: error: incompatible types: PrintableForms cannot be converted to Component
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, "Printing", type);
```

My code is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;

public class PrintableForms
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("This is my title");

    JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel();

    JButton btnDoc1 = new JButton();
    JButton btnP1 = new JButton();

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    String []fontFamilies = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    Font FontT5 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 50);
    ///////////
    JCheckBox backgroundCheck = new JCheckBox();
    JCheckBox interactiveCheck = new JCheckBox();
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    JTextField headerField = new JTextField();
    JTextField footerField = new JTextField();

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 1200, 500);
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createFirstPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
        load(text, "Athlete.txt");
    }

    public void createFirstPanel()
    {
        firstPanel.setLayout(null);

        btnDoc1.setLocation(10,120);
        btnDoc1.setSize(900,50);
        btnDoc1.setText("Update Personal Information");
        btnDoc1.setFont(FontT5);
        firstPanel.add(btnDoc1);

        btnP1.setLocation(910,120);
        btnP1.setSize(250,50);
        btnP1.setText("Print");
        btnP1.setFont(FontT5);
        btnP1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                print(evt);
            }
        });
        firstPanel.add(btnP1);


        footerField.setText("Page {0}");
        headerField.setText("Athlete Form");
        backgroundCheck.setSelected(true);
        interactiveCheck.setSelected(true);
    }

    private void load(JTextArea comp, String fileName) {
        try {
            comp.read(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)),
                null);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void print(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        MessageFormat header = createFormat(headerField);
        MessageFormat footer = createFormat(footerField);
        boolean interactive = interactiveCheck.isSelected();
        boolean background = backgroundCheck.isSelected();

        PrintingTask task = new PrintingTask(header, footer, interactive);
        if (background) 
        {
            task.execute();
        } 

        else 
        {
            task.run();
        }
    }

    private class PrintingTask extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> 
    {
        private final MessageFormat headerFormat;
        private final MessageFormat footerFormat;
        private final boolean interactive;
        private volatile boolean complete = false;
        private volatile String message;
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

        public PrintingTask(MessageFormat header, MessageFormat footer, boolean interactive) 
        {
            this.headerFormat = header;
            this.footerFormat = footer;
            this.interactive = interactive;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() {
            try {
                complete = text.print(headerFormat, footerFormat,
                        true, null, null, interactive);
                message = "Printing " + (complete ? "complete" : "canceled");
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                message = "Sorry, a printer error occurred";
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                message =
                    "Sorry, cannot access the printer due to security reasons";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            message(!complete, message);
        }
    }

    private MessageFormat createFormat(JTextField source) {
        //String text = new Scanner( new File("Athlete.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        String text = source.getText();
        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
            try {
                return new MessageFormat(text);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                error("Sorry, this format is invalid.");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void message(boolean error, String msg) 
    {
        int type = (error ? JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE :
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, "Printing", type);
    }

    private void error(String msg) 
    {
        message(true, msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintableForms pf = new PrintableForms();
        pf.runGUI();
    }
}
```

I am trying to get it so when I click a button, `btnP1` in this case, it opens a dialog and then allows you to print off a pre-set document. In this code that document is Athlete.txt and all it reads is `This is a test`

I would any help in fixing this problem, Thanks

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog expects an Component object as first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass on the frame object which is the main window that you created when you want to show the dialog window.

Like below.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myMainWindow, msg, "Printing", type);
```

Comment: Out of interest is there any reason it would fail to print?

Comment: If you look at the code in the below lines.  load(text, "Athlete.txt"); here you are loading the file contents "comp.read( new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)),
                null);" . but inside the PrintingTask class you are again creating a new JTextArea. "JTextArea text = new JTextArea();". so that is the reason the printing is failing. Remove the creation of JTextArea in the PrintingTask.

Comment: Remove "JTextArea text = new JTextArea();" this line in PrintingTask class.

Answer (score 2):

you should extends **Component** class or create Component type object and pass as argument instead of ***this*** because

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg, "Printing", type);`

first argument is of **Component** Type and you are passing parameter of type **PrintableForms** as ***this*** .

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the `Printable` interface.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
When giving an answer it is preferable to give some explanation as to WHY your answer is the one.